# How to decrement months on a php datetime object until it matches the month of a second date time object?

Tags: php, datetime, decrement

I have two objects $o_NewRegDate (registration date) and $o_NewNowDate(current date).

If we dump the year and month for $o_NewRegDate:

```
var_dump (date_format($o_NewRegDate, 'Y-m'));

string '2009-09' (length=7)
```

If we dump the year and month for  $o_NewNowDate:

```
var_dump (date_format($o_NewNowDate, 'Y-m'));

    string '2013-09' (length=7)
```

What is the best way to decrement the months in $o_NewNowDate (storing each iteration in an array) until we reach the year and month of $o_NewRegDate?

Desired Output array would be something like this:

```
array (size=61)
  '2013-09-01' => string '09-2013' (length=7)
  '2013-08-01' => string '08-2013' (length=7)
  '2013-07-01' => string '07-2013' (length=7)
  (...)
  '2010-01-01' => string '01-2010' (length=7)
  '2009-12-01' => string '12-2009' (length=7)
  '2009-11-01' => string '11-2009' (length=7)
  '2009-10-01' => string '10-2009' (length=7)
  '2009-09-01' => string '09-2009' (length=7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$o_NewRegDate = '2009-09-01';
$o_NewNowDate = '2013-09-18';

$startDate = new \DateTime($o_NewNowDate);
echo 'Start date: ', $startDate->format('Y-m-d') , PHP_EOL;
$endDate = new \DateTime($o_NewRegDate);
echo 'End date: ', $endDate->format('Y-m-d') , PHP_EOL;

$interval = new \DateInterval('P1M');
$monthPeriod = new \DatePeriod ($endDate, $interval, $startDate);

foreach ($monthPeriod as $key => $monthDate) {
   echo $monthDate->format('Y-m') , PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! Your solution together with trzyeM- ´s solution for building the final array is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$o_NewRegDate = '2009-09-01'; $o_NewNowDate = '2013-09-01'; 
$iDateStart = strtotime( $o_NewRegDate  );
$iDateEnd = strtotime( $o_NewNowDate );
$iEnd = ( $iDateEnd - $iDateStart ) / 2678400; //60*60*24*31
$aDate = array();
for( $i = 0; $i <= $iEnd; $i++ ) {
   $aDate[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'. $i .' month', $iDateStart));
}
$aDate = array_reverse( $aDate );
```

improve by yourself especially $iEnd variable.

Comment: Thanks man! Your solution for building the final array is what I needed. Setting the $interval and $monthPeriod like Mark Baker suggested seems a little more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

use this simple code.

```
$date2='2014-07-12';
$monthArr=explode('-',$date2);
$numDays=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $monthArr[1], $monthArr[2]);
$tempDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date2));
$regDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-$numDays days",strtotime($tempDate)));
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please add more information when answering questions so that users fully understand how to implement your solution.